# AttributeError: module 'tox.config' has no attribute 'parseini'

Tags: python, travis-ci, python-3.5, tox

I recently get

```
3.36s$ pip install coveralls tox-travis
0.31s$ tox
Matching undeclared envs is deprecated. Be sure all the envs that Tox should run are declared in the tox config.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.5.6/bin/tox", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(cmdline())
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.5.6/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tox/session.py", line 41, in cmdline
    main(args)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.5.6/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tox/session.py", line 46, in main
    config = prepare(args)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.5.6/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tox/session.py", line 28, in prepare
    config = parseconfig(args)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.5.6/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tox/config.py", line 233, in parseconfig
    pm.hook.tox_configure(config=config)  # post process config object
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.5.6/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pluggy/hooks.py", line 258, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self._nonwrappers + self._wrappers, kwargs)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.5.6/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 67, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.5.6/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 61, in <lambda>
    firstresult=hook.spec_opts.get('firstresult'),
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.5.6/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 201, in _multicall
    return outcome.get_result()
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.5.6/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 76, in get_result
    raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.5.6/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 180, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.5.6/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tox_travis/hooks.py", line 46, in tox_configure
    autogen_envconfigs(config, undeclared)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.5.6/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tox_travis/envlist.py", line 48, in autogen_envconfigs
    make_envconfig = tox.config.parseini.make_envconfig
AttributeError: module 'tox.config' has no attribute 'parseini'
The command "tox" exited with 1.
```

for the [mpu project](https://github.com/MartinThoma/mpu) ([travis link](https://travis-ci.org/MartinThoma/mpu/jobs/431564761))

The strange thing is that it works for Python 2.7 and Python 3.6 - so what is the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Tox 3.4.0 (released yesterday) broke tox-travis: https://github.com/tox-dev/tox-travis/issues/114

The bug is already fixed and the new release [0.11](https://pypi.org/project/tox-travis/0.11/) just uploaded. Upgrade:

```
pip install -U 'tox-travis>=0.11'
```